# help needed for SNMP protocol

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I need some information and guidance about `SNMP`, I am new in development so I need help.
I studied `SNMP protocol` in detail(MIB,OID, and how it works),

I have some questions

- can we change read-only Access of MIB objects to read-write Access?
- Can we change Standard MIB to our own requirements?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2):

In a few scenarios, you may change a read-write object to read-only object. But I don't think you can do the opposite.

If you need to meet your own requirements, you may write your own MIB documents and add custom objects. Don't change standard objects, as that breaks the standard.

Comment: for reply. I studied it on net-snmp mailing list that no one can change standard RFC,

Comment: now i tried following steps but no success yet. tried to write new Private MIB and load it to net-snmp by following tutorial from net-snmp website. i studied Agent Arch as well but dont know where i should change in code to inform or handle my MIB in it.